# ControlTemplate TargetType does not match templated type

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have created this usercontrol in WPF

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:UserControl1}">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Margin="7,7,7,0">
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```

When I compile this I get the following error.

'UserControl1' ControlTemplate TargetType does not match templated type 'UserControl'.

But when I debug the application it works fine.

What does this error mean? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Why do you have the ControlTemplate at all, when you could declare the Grid directly as Content of the UserControl?

Comment: This is a simplified example in the actual use case the content has multiple controls

Comment: And without the controltemplate the contents won't be displayed. Sorry for the double post I was to late with my edit.

Comment: You cannot debug an application without compiling it first...and your markup should be just fine.

Comment: I agree normally you can't debug an application with error. But this error still allows you to start the program. That is what is strange.

Answer (score 5):

The error most likely only shows up when you have the XAML editor open, right?  This is because it is a XAML Designer problem, not a WPF or .NET problem.  That is why it works fine when you run, but shows an error in Visual Studio.

I am having similar issues because the XAML Designer also does not support polymorphism on ControlTemplates (template's TargetType="baseclass", but is applied to a derived class) - yet this also work at runtime.

The main workaround is to not define your custom control using XAML.  Instead, create a templated control, where the template is selected by an external style resource.  See http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-a-custom-control-in-xaml-and-c/26447 for more information.

Comment: Hey Jeff, having a similar issue and came upon your reply. Could you elaborate on template selection by an external source? Thanks, Shaun

Comment: The link does not work anymore.